# Linear regression to find differences between model performances

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, model-evaluations

For one of my projects I needed to create classification models for each of many products. In order to see which classifier performs best, I created one SVM, RandomForest and Naive Bayes model for each product doing a 5-fold cross validation in the process. I saved the model and the scores for each fold (so 15 models and scores per product).

Now I want to take a look why some models perform much better than others. For this I plan to do a linear regression, where the y value is the model score (e.g. precision, recall, ...) and the x values are one-hot encoded categorical variables. For illustrative purposes lets say there are two categorical variables: color = ["red", "green", "yellow"], age_group = ["children", "teenager", "adults"]. Basically what I want to see is if there is a significant difference in the score depending on the color and/or the age_group.

From this I encountered the following questions:

What would signify one sample in my linear regression? Does it make sense to take each fold as its own sample? I expect that this is not the correct way since then samples would not be independent. Instead my approach would be to take the best performing estimator of the three and use the mean score as a sample. Therefore I would only have one sample per product. Alternatively, I think it might also be fine to introduce a third categorical variable which signifies the estimator. Then I could include the mean score of the 5 folds for each estimator in the samples, therefore including 3 samples per product (again here I am not sure if I would violate independence of the samples).

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You could probably add a "model fixed-effect", so a "dummy" that indicates each model type. https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/10-3-fixed-effects-regression.html

Comment: There is the mention of "perform better" and mention of precision/recall.  How is performance measured? If it is a non-proper scoring rule, then was the cut-off value for each algorithm and each fold optimized or was a default used? Is the default the right choice in all cases? Just because one of the algorithms may have given a different score to the same observations, does not mean that algorithm is "worse". Maybe all of the scores are lower by one of the algorithms.

Comment: Overall the models are optimized in terms of sklearns average precision score: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html 
The algorithms work differently well depending on the product so that for one product SVM might perform the best, whereas for another the RandomForest model might have the highest score. 

The goal is mainly though to find if there is an influence of the independent variables above (color, age_group) on the average precision score (diving deeper I might also look at other performance metrics).